# SharePoint Live Tile Notifications

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint, winjs, sharepoint-2013

I've been searching for some resources on SharePoint '13 Workflow integration with Windows 8 live tiles including MSDN, multiple blogs (such as http://www.howtosp.com/blog/). I've found a variety of sources for programming live tiles into SharePoint, and SharePoint to Mobile Push notifications (But no specifics if this will work on Win 8 Pro), and I am just trying to find out if I can cause parts of a SharePoint '13 workflow to interact with an active Windows 8 Live Tile. For example in a workflow, if step 3 is on hold for a given amount of time either flash a message across the tile, a color, etc. Any help, direction, resouces are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Alex